# Entity Framework 5 column mapping datetime

Tags: entity-framework-5

this does not seem to work:

```
this.Property(t => t.mydatetime)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")
    .HasColumnName("mydatetime");
```

looking at sql profiler the update sql string still uses datetime2(7) and uses the extra decimal places.  The result of this is rounding differences between datetime2 and datetime.

how can I force entity framework to use datetime sql type?

Thank You!

Comment: Can't repro that. `HasColumnType("datetime")` creates a `datatime` column (Sql Server 2008 r2, EF 5).

Comment: my db already has a datetime column. I am not using EF to create the DB. I am also using sql 2008 r2

Comment: Hmmm... more relevant information?

Comment: @Gert - an easy way to repro this is have an existing db with a datetime column.  Save the model with the datetime property in code set to DateTime.Now.  Looking at the sql EF generates it uses datetime2 even though you specified .HasCOlumnType("datetime")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasColumnType("datetime")` specifies the column type, not the temporary parameter types that are used in the SQL statements. You can't control those and it's not necessary. If you have a .NET `DateTime` in your application with some decimal places filled and want to store that in a `datetime` type in SQL Server the value will (and can only) be stored as a rounded value. It doesn't matter if the rounding happens on client side before the SQL is sent to the database server or if the rounding happens on the database server itself. The result will be the same: A rounded stored value with a loss of precision.

Comment: the problem is we have two code paths that save the same datetime .net object. one code path uses ef and the other does not. since Ef sends 7 (datetime2) decimal places and the other sends 3 (datetime) it causes a rounding issues when saved to the db. This did not happen with EF4.